# "Whenever I was" vs "Whenever I got"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Is there any notable difference between the two? Example:

> Whenever I **was** depressed, sounds would amplify themselves ten or
>   twenty times, to the point they became indistinguishable from physical
>   pain.
>
> Whenever I **got** depressed, sounds would amplify themselves ten or
>   twenty times, to the point they became indistinguishable from physical
>   pain.

Does the meaning change? Or maybe one of the options is incorrect/not idiomatic?

Comment: To me, ***got*** *depressed* seems to suggest episodes of depression that did not last as long as those the speaker had when he ***was*** *depressed*. (Others may disagree.)

Comment: @ErikKowal - I don't get that sense (for AmE at least). *Got* is just a lower register for *became*. "I *became* sick", if anything, implies duration unspecified, while "I *was* sick" merely states a condition. Anyway, the examples are both very idiomatic.

Comment: Agree wth Erik I become sick relates to the starting point of the sickness and I am sick to the simple state of sickness.

Comment: According to [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/get-passive), talking about the 'get-passive': 'We use the get passive especially in informal speaking. When we use the get passive, we also place a little more emphasis on the nature of the action itself or on the person involved in the action [than we do when we use the ordinary passive].' Surely other {be + -ed form} and {get + -ed form} constructions reflect (or perhaps more probably inform) this difference in emphasis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Get depressed* (or *angry*, or *cold*, or *comfortable*, or most physical or emotional states) is an informal equivalent to *become depressed* etc.

So *whenever I got depressed* focuses the moments when I became depressed, while *whenever I was depressed* focuses on the times when I was in a state of depression. For many purposes they are interchangeable.